# How to Create Multiple Logger Folder

Tags: node.js, express, logging, winston

I want to create multiple logger folder one for SignUp and another one for SignIn, I have created for Sign up and want the same for SignIn,
I am new to nodejs, Please tell how to do same for Sign in

Here is the code for SignUp

```
const chalk = require("chalk")
const log = console.log;
const winston = require('winston')
myFormat = () => {
    return new Date(Date.now())
}
class LoggerService {
    constructor(service) {
        this.log_data = null
        this.service = service
        const logger = winston.createLogger({
            transports: [
                new winston.transports.Console(),
                new winston.transports.File({
                    filename: `./logs/${service}/${myFormat().getUTCFullYear()}/${myFormat().getUTCMonth()+1}/${myFormat().getUTCDate()}.log`
                })
            ],
            format: winston.format.printf((info) => {
                let message = `${myFormat().toUTCString()} | ${info.level.toUpperCase()} | ${service}.log | ${info.message} | `
                message = info.obj ? message + `data:${JSON.stringify(info.obj)} | ` : message
                message = this.log_data ? message + `log_data:${JSON.stringify(this.log_data)} | ` : message
                return message
            })
        });
        this.logger = logger
    }
    setLogData(log_data) {
        this.log_data = log_data
    }
    async info (message) {
        this.logger.log('info', message);
    }
    async info(message, obj) {
        this.logger.log('info', message, {
            obj
        })
    }
    async debug(message) {
        this.logger.log('debug', message);
    }
    async debug(message, obj) {
        this.logger.log('debug', message, {
            obj
        })
    }
    async error(message) {
       this.logger.log('error', message);
    }
    async error (message, obj) {
        this.logger.log('error',message, {
            obj
         })
    }
}
module.exports = LoggerService
```

Please tell how I create same for Sign In

userAuth.js file

```
const log = console.log;
const Logger = require("../logs/services/logger_service");
const logger = new Logger("SignUp");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you ever got this resolved but the way I did it is below. In my case I create custom levels like below and a function which will apply the filter as well added the filter to the transport. With this you can create as many files you want and filter. In this case only the level you select will be logged so if you select signup only signup events will go to that transport.

```
var customLevels = {
  levels: {
    debug: 0,
    info: 1,
    express: 2,
    mail: 3,
    couchbase: 4,
    sql: 5,
    security : 6,
    blacklist: 7,
    warning: 8,
    error: 9
  },
  colors: {
    debug: 'cyan',
    info: 'green',
    warning: 'yellow',
    error: 'red'
  }
}
```

then i have a function called levelFilter()

```
const levelFilter = (level) =>
  format((info, opts) => {
     if (info.level != level) { return false; }
      return info;
  })();
```

And then create my Transport like this

```
var logger = createLogger({ 
    level : logLevel,
    levels: customLevels.levels,
    format: combine(
        timestamp(),
        format.timestamp({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS'
           }),
        myFormat
      ),
transports: [
 new transports.DailyRotateFile({
    filename: logPath + '/app/application-%DATE%.log',
    datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH',
    zippedArchive: true,
    frequency: '60m',
    maxSize: '20m',
    maxFiles: '14d',
    level: 'info',
    format: levelFilter("info")
  })....
```